# GetLegendGraphic - how to align graphic symbols and layer name in one line

Tags: geoserver, getlegendgraphic

I want to create legend using GetLegendGraphic.

For some reason graphic symbols and layer names are located in different lines:

[image]

I need to have them the same as shown in the documentation for GetLegendGraphic https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/index.html

[image]

How that can be managed?

Is it possible also to increase white margins around the legend?

My request is:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetLegendGraphic&layer=testWorkspace:LayerGroup1_legend&format=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=10&legend_options=fontName:Times New Roman;fontAntiAliasing:true;fontColor:0x000033;fontSize:10;dpi:180;rowwidth=200
```

playing with different rowwidth and without it. But it doesn't change anything

Comment: we'd need to see the actual request to be sure but making the legend wider might help

Comment: Thanks, I have adjusted question adding request.